# React Native App As Tcp Client

Tags: react-native

How can I connect my React native App with Tcp server built in GOLang.
I want to make my app a tcp client to that server currently i am using react-native-socket.io-client but server did not give any response that someone connected

Comment: Could you provide some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

I have done that using https://github.com/PeelTechnologies/react-native-tcp plugin to connect App to Tcp Server